# ASP.NET web api - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In our asp.net mvc/web api project, we want to customize the authorization using `AuthorizeAttribute`. We have noticed that there are two different `AuthorizeAttribute`, one in `System.Web.MVC` namespace for MVC and the other in `System.Net.Http` namespace for web api.

It works in MVC, our code like this:

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    //some custom properties
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        //custom authentication logic
    }

    private IIdentity identity;
    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return this.identity; }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//override AuthorizeCore
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        MyPrincipal user = new MyPrincipal();

        if (user.isValid())
        {
            httpContext.User = user;
        }
        else
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Common/NoAuthorize", true);
        }
    }
}

[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
public class BaseMyController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new MyPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as MyPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

Then in MVC controller,we can get the user information via `MyPrincipal` user property.

However, when we start to use the same way in web api, we found that the web api has no `HttpContext` property and in `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, the method to be override accepts a `HttpActionContext` argument, it also has no `HttpContext` property or some where else we can set the `MyPrincipal` instance.

I notice that the `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` summary says

> *Specifies the authorization filter that verifies the request's IPrincipal*

It seems that there is some other way to set the `IPrincipal` instance.

I have no idea about it, any good advice? By the way, why does the asp.net web api controller have no `HttpContext`? Is there any design pattern about it?

The related questions
[ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I implemented something as a proof of concept following mostly this: [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

For Web API you can create an Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter.
If I remember rightly, you can add it as a filter to the global filters in WebApiConfig

```
config.Filters.Add(new YourAuthenticationAttribute());
```

Or you can use it as an attribute on the api controller/ method.

You can then implement AuthenticateAsync, get the request's authorization header, check the scheme, and validate the parameter, and if all is valid, set the principal.

I think the idea is that you can add multiple of these filters in a chain and they can all authenticate against a specific set of requirements, like the scheme they look for, and somewhere in the chain the principal gets set, or a challenge is returned.

```
public class YourAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{

public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;

if (request.Headers.Authorization != null &&
    request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme.Equals("yourScheme", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // get the value sent with the header.
        string authParam = request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

        // do some validation on the parameter provided...
        // if it's all valid, create a principal with claims:


    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Eddie Admin"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
        // new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Delete"),
    };

    // create an identity with the valid claims.
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "yourScheme");

    // set the context principal.
    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
```

When creating the principal you can apply claims and these are checked against the normal authorize attribute. e.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

I haven't used it beyond doing this, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks!`context.Principal` is exactly what I need,but our protect is based on asp.net web api,not web api 2,I cannot implement the interface `IAuthenticationFilter`.Fortunately,your link [ Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) helps me a lot and I find a alternative way in asp.net web api [Basic Authentication in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication). It implement a http module instead.

Comment: [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] is giving me "Authorization has been denied for this request." When I define my custom Authorization it works.
public class MyCustomAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
 {
  if (!actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
   actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
  }
  base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
 }
}
finally, 
[MyCustomAuthorize] 
public class EmployeeController : ApiController 
{

}

Answer (score 1):

This `AuthorizeAttribute` implementation worked for me. It's designed for [Http Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) but obviously I want to get the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.Name` from inside a `ApiController` too and this works:

```
public class ApiAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var session = (ISession)actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ISession));

        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            var authConcat = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter));
            var email = authConcat.Split(':')[0];
            var password = authConcat.Split(':')[1];

            var user = session.Query<UserAccount>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
            if (user != null && user.IsAuthenticated(password))
            {
                actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.Email), new string[] { });
                return;     // and continue with controller
            }
        }

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in WebApi I could only use ControllerContext. But I'm not sure exactly why. From What I read, HttpContext is thread static, but everything in WebApi is more or less async. Take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956178/using-httpcontext-current-in-webapi-is-dangerous-because-of-async), maybe it will answer some questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your `IPrincipal`.

```
public static class IPrincipalExtension
{
   public static bool IsValid(this IPrincipal p)
   {
       // your custom validation
       return true;
   }
}
```

Now reference your namespace and use like this.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var valid = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsValid(); // this will return boolean
        // your code here


    }
}
```