# SiteContext is null when using Web API 2 with Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, kentico

I've implemented Web API 2 with a Kentico 9 CMS platform (generally following [Kentico's documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k82/developing-websites/using-asp-net-web-api-with-kentico)) and on the whole it's working well. However, in my controllers I'm finding `SiteContext.CurrentSite` always returns null. Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Not sure if it makes a difference but the platform hosts multiple sites under a single domain as per [this documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/setting-up-multiple-websites/running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-domain). So my sites are running at the following URLs...

- domain.com/site1
- domain.com/site2
- etc.

...and the API is available under the following paths...

- domain.com/site1/customapi
- domain.com/site2/customapi
- etc.

Currently I'm having to use the Request object to pull out the request path and check this against the sites from Kentico's `SiteProvider` to find which Kentico site the current request relates to, but I wouldn't have though that necessary since the API is running as part of the site.

Is there something I can do to wire this up properly? FYI I've noticed that `LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture` does return a `CultureInfo` object so it's not as though I'm completely disconnected from Kentico's context...

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

Thanks to @martin-makarsky for the answer below. Used this to create the following extension method which can be called from controller using `Request.GetCurrentSite()`

```
public static SiteInfo GetCurrentSite(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return SiteInfoProvider.GetRunningSiteInfo(request.RequestUri.Host, System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, nobody answered this question so I`ll give it a try. SiteContext uses  internally  `HttpContext.Current` which is little bit 'unreliable' in web api due to some [thread and async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956178/using-httpcontext-current-in-webapi-is-dangerous-because-of-async) related stuff (does your action contain await?). This could explain your `nulls` when calling `SiteContext.CurrentSite` in your controller.

So back to your problem - you need to get current `SiteInfo` inside you app (probably web api controller or service or repository) - this means you likely know your current domain or appPath. I would try to use something from `SiteInfoProvider`
like `GetRunningSiteInfo(string domainName, string applicationPath)` to get current `SiteInfo`.

Good luck!

Comment: Funny enough, I just came across this question when faced with the same problem again! Sorry I didn't mark as the answer before. You're spot on, this is the correct answer. See my edit above for an extension method which uses this approach.